# which class defines the keywords in java?

Tags: java, keyword

Could anybody tell me in which class are the keywords like `public` and `protected` defined? I searched all over the internet but i couldn't find the answer.

Comment: keywords are not defined in any class, they are just keywords

Comment: is it possible the OP means "in the openjdk sources" ?

Answer (score 4):

The Java keywords are described in the [The Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html). Details can be found in [this table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9).

Answer (score 0):

Yes what gefei said. You can't search the javadocs for the definition of 'public'.

You can however find the specification [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.9).

Comment: @Tichodroma: But I don't think there have been any keywords added since then.

Comment: AFAIK 'public' hasn't really changed. So it's still usable.

Comment: Specification just gives the list of keywords. Where is the behavior of these keywords defined? What does compiler do when it encounters a keyword? Where does it look ?

Comment: Here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/names.html#6.6

Answer (score 0):

It is implementation specific. 
For example see:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/compiler-grammar/compiler-grammar/langtools/file/dc7563e2b917/src/share/classes/javax/lang/model/element/Modifier.java

Comment: That's not the complete list of all keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Those are spcial key words that are called modfier and are avaiable from here

`java.lang.reflect.Modifier`

Comment: That's not the complete list of all keywords.

Comment: @Tichodroma, Quoting after OP `keyword like public and protected`. The like narrow all keywords to modyfiers only IMHO.

Comment: For a suitable value of 'like' this might be true.

Comment: Modifier class doesn't define modifiers. It provides methods that are used to decode the access modifiers. That wasn't my question.

Comment: @SandeepDhamija, in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html) you have the Filed Summary that represent Modifier suported by Java.